# codeigniter insert to mysql with external variable

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am sending my form in `$post`, that means jquery post, to a file called: *register.php*

Now my variable called "name" ... so in **register.php** this is my code:

```
<?php
include "external.php";
$CI->load->database();
$fullName=$_REQUEST['name'];
$data = array(
            'full_name' => $fullName
        );
$CI->db->insert('tbl_users', 'full_name'=>'');
if( $_REQUEST["name"] ) {

   $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
   echo "Welcome ". $name;
}

?>
```

the *external.php* is to load Codeigniter.

REQUEST name is what I want to insert to db...

the code is inserting to db [full_name table] an empty name.. and I got this problem:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be
>   resource, boolean given
>
> Filename: mysql/mysql_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 314

How can I insert the `$_REQUEST["name"]` to the database ?

Comment: documentation shows how to use array for insert. Also should use input class to assign the request values and do some validation also

Comment: my problem is here: 'full_name' => $fullName

Comment: You should switch your driver to mysqli in `application/config/database.php`

Comment: @Gwendal what do you mean ?

Comment: It will not solve your problem, but you are using the mysql driver which is deprecated since php 5.5 and removed in php 7. You should change to mysqli, it'll not change anything in your application

Answer (score 0):

In view

```
 <?php echo form_open_multipart(base_url().'moderator/B2BCategory/insertname'); ?>
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="txtcatname">Title of Category :</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="txtname" class="form-control" id="txtname" placeholder="Category Name " required="required">
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

In your controller

```
 public function insertname() {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->view('moderator/templates/header');
        $this->load->view('moderator/templates/sidebar');
         if ($this->input->post('selsub')) {
 $data = array('db_name' => $this->input->post('name'));
 $this->b2bcategory_model->form_insert($data);
            }
}
```

In Model

```
public function form_insert($data){
$this->db->insert('jil_category', $data);
}
```

I am sure this wil help you

Comment: but i want to insert to DB in an external file...without loading a controller or something

Comment: this code wil help you to insert the name to the database.

Comment: do you want to write the data in the database to a file?

Comment: i mean...i am using a Modal in bootstrap to register.....now in this modal i am sending the data to page called: "register.php" ... it is unappearable file...it just insert and get the results to the Modal in bootstrap....now what i am trying to do is to insert from register.php....i attached the file in the original post

Comment: where is that file? but you can pass values from the modal bootstrap to controller and then to database,thats the easy way.